# How to set hints in OpenGL ES 2?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es

In previous versions of OpenGL, you could set various hints such as `GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT`, and set the shade model to `GL_SMOOTH`. How can you do this in OpenGL ES 2?

The only hint target in ES is `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT` and other things such as 1D textures are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_SMOOTH` and other lighting related (or even matrix projection) hints are not something you can hint at OpenGL ES 2.0 to do because this functionality must be implemented in the programmable shader pipeline which is left to the developer to implement in OpenGL ES 2.0 and is not handled by OpenGL ES as it was in the 1.x versions.

However, OpenGL ES 2.0 still handles mip-map generation. That is why hints like `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT` are still valid.